# Player should win when all objects are collected

Tags: scripting, unity-game-engine

I have a simple game where the player needs to collect 4 game objects within 30 sec. Now I already created the timer, so I need to let the game know that if all game objects are collected under the time limit the player wins.

This is my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameState : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static int count = 0;

    public float seconds = 30;
    public float minutes = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (seconds <= 0) 
        {
            seconds = 30;
            if (minutes >= 1)
            {
                minutes -- ;
            }
            else
            {
                minutes = 0;
                seconds = 0;

                GameObject.Find("TimerText").guiText.text = minutes.ToString("f0") + ":0" + seconds.ToString("f0");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Mathf.Round(seconds) <=9)
        {
            GameObject.Find("TimerText").guiText.text = minutes.ToString("f0") + ":0" + seconds.ToString("f0");
        }
        else
        {
            GameObject.Find("TimerText").guiText.text = minutes.ToString("f0") + ":" + seconds.ToString("f0");
        }

        if(count >= 1)  
        {
            print("You Won!");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collide)
    {
        if (collide.transform.tag == "Cube") 
        {
            count = count + 1;
            Destroy (collide.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: cube is one of the game object that needs to be picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could interrupt the game or show a victory menu or something when you have all the cubes collected

```
void Update () 
{
   bool cubescollected = false;
   if(cubescollected == 4)
   {
      ShowVictoryOrSomething();
      cubescollected = true
   }
   if(cubescollected == true)
      return;
... your timer code
}
```

good luck and happy coding